# Does SVG offer better performance than plain HTML to render text labels in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, html, svg, performance

I'm using Leaflet built-in L.DivIcon to add text labels to my map. Text labels are rendered in simple HTML divs and can be rotated and scaled using CSS based on values obtained from geojson data properties.

I would like to know if using SVG (with for example d3.js) to render my labels would allow faster panning and zooming than my actual HTML/div implementation ?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I doubt SVG labels would be faster than plain html.

Comment: A more answerable question might be "Are there any performance test results available to indicate which option is faster?"

Comment: Still looking for working code of HOW one can do that.